# read from a local text file and update and updating the content in an html tag

Tags: javascript, localhost, local

I need to read a local text file and update my html page with the contents of the text file. 
I do not have so much browser support as I work on an embedded system.

But it gave the following error :

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/aryas/Desktop/localtoken.txt. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.`

The code is as follows.

```
   <script>

window.onload = function readTextFile()
{
    console.log("Inside function");
    var file = "localtoken.txt";
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
            {
                var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                document.getElementById("token").innerHTML = allText;

            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}
</script>
```

Comment: please mention that which device/browser you are expecting the code to run.

Comment: You are not going to be able to use XMLHttpRequest to accomplish this, nor are you going to be able to use the HTML5 file access API as they require the user to select the file manually. Have you investigated LocalStorage? or considered storing the file data remotely?

Comment: @Shiva Working in a custom browser created using Qt. It's on an xi3 set top box.

Comment: @AlexK. Could you please explain a bit more on what is meant by LocalStorage? Storing the file remotely is not possible it seems. It must reside locally.

Answer (score 0):

Put this text file at the same directory as your index.html.
In an ajax request you path will look like it's on you website - 'readfile.txt'

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass file URL into XMLHttpRequest.

```
xmlhttp.open('GET', 'http://localhost/file.txt', false);
```

For this you need to configure a webserver which can process your request. For instance you can install Apache server and bring it up and deploy file.txt into it. Once the browser sends request to webserver for file.txt the webserver returns you the file and the response you can process with the same approach what you have mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**
You cannot do what you want, as you are doing it right now. You have to serve the files in a web server. Try [LightHTTPD](http://www.lighttpd.net/), [Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/) or [Mongoose](https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/)

---

**Long answer:**
From the error you're getting, you must be opening the index.html file (the file with the script) without serving it from a web server (to confirm this, let me ask: does the URL in the browser start with `file://`?).

As the class name states, `XMLHttpRequest` only supports HTTP/HTTPS requests (blob URIs are in development, as stated here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest).

As in matter of fact, you will not be able to load/save files from your file system without the user to manually choose the file(s), as this is a security threat (imagine you open a website and it loads your `C:` and sends it to the server, do you want a website to do it?).

For loading your `localtoken.txt` file, serve the files in a light and small webserver (as you are working on an embedded system). The ones I suggested in the short answer fill these requirements, but from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738273/open-source-c-c-embedded-web-server) it seems that Mongoose is the way to go.